# 2 columns on a left join

Tags: php, mysql, join

Hello so I have 2 tables. `tbl_records` and `tbl_guards`. On `tbl_guards` I have guard_id and on `tbl_records` I have `guard_id` and `guard_id_in`. And here is my current code:

```
try
    {
    $stat = "0";
    $query = "SELECT rec.*, tbl_guard.fname, tbl_guard.lname
FROM tbl_records as rec
LEFT JOIN tbl_guard ON tbl_guard.guard_id = rec.guard_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_records ON tbl_records.guard_id_in = tbl_guard.guard_id
    WHERE rec.stud_id=? AND rec.status=?";

    $stmt  = $dbc->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $_GET['id']);
    $stmt->bindParam(2, $stat);
    $stmt->execute();
    echo "<table cellpadding='3' class='searchTbl'>";
    echo "<thead>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th>Actual Date</th>";
    echo "<th>Purpose</th>";
    echo "<th>Destination</th>";
    echo "<th>Exact TO</th>";
    echo "<th>Expected TI</th>";
    echo "<th>Guard</th>";
    echo "<th>Actual TI</th>";
    echo "<th>Guard IN</th>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</thead>";
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        extract($row);
        $guard = $fname . " " . $lname;
        echo "<tbody>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>$act_date</td>";
        echo "<td>$purpose</td>";
        echo "<td>$destination</td>";
        echo "<td>$exact_timeout</td>";
        echo "<td>$exp_timein</td>";
        echo "<td>$guard</td>";
        echo "<td>$act_timein</td>";
        echo "<td>$guard</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "</tbody>";
        }
    }
catch (PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
echo "</table>";
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y54Jt.png) is `tbl_records` data.
And [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1sit.png) is `tbl_guard` data.
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzsny.png) is the current output.

My problem is it shows the same guard in `guard_id` and `guard_id_in` in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should select twice the guard table and use aliases for your fields :

```
SELECT tr1.*, tg1.fname AS FNAME, tg1.lname AS LNAME, 
       tg2.fname AS FNAME_IN, tg2.lname AS LNAME_IN 
FROM tbl_records AS tr1 
LEFT JOIN tbl_guard AS tg1 
     ON tg1.guard_id = tr1.guard_id, 
LEFT JOIN tbl_guard AS tg2 
     ON tg2.guard_id = trl.guard_id_in
```

then in PHP you'll have more vars : $FNAME, $LNAME, $FNAME_IN, $LNAME_IN

Answer (score 4):

You can use `LEFT JOIN` multiple times, like:

```
SELECT tbl_records.*, tbl_guard.fname, tbl_guard.lname
FROM tbl_records as rec
LEFT JOIN tbl_guard ON tbl_guard.guard_id = rec.guard_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_records ON tbl_records.guard_id_in = tbl_guard.guard_id
```

Comment: It gives me this error
Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'tbl_records'

Comment: Hello what does this mean?  
Error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'stud_id' in where clause is ambiguous  
Here is my complete code:  
SELECT tbl_records.*, tbl_guard.fname, tbl_guard.lname
FROM tbl_records as rec
LEFT JOIN tbl_guard ON tbl_guard.guard_id = rec.guard_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_records ON tbl_records.guard_id_in = tbl_guard.guard_id WHERE stud_id=? AND status=?

Comment: It means that more than one table have a column named "stud_id". So you have to change "stud_id" by (i.e.) "rec.stud_id". Or whatever table you want to use.

Comment: It works but it only echos same guard in guard_id and guard_id_in

Comment: It would be much easier to help when you provide a sqlfiddle.com with your table schema and a few example data. And with your expected output. Maybe left join is the wrong thing.

Comment: I'm still learning sqlfiddle and will provide better questions, but for now this is my current [code](http://paste.ofcode.org/CrgySiDJWnhGz5CaDZKXKW) and this is my [tbl_records](http://i.imgur.com/H7undVJ.png) and this is my [tbl_guard](http://i.imgur.com/Vo26VAR.png) and what it outputs is [this](http://i.imgur.com/cDG5GDv.png)

Comment: You should go with @Taace Teece 's Answer. Take a look at that fiddle with example data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/df884/2

Answer (score 2):

```
You can use:

SELECT tbl_records.*, tbl_guard.fname, tbl_guard.lname 
FROM tbl_records 
LEFT JOIN tbl_guard ON (tbl_records.guard_id OR tbl_records.guard_id_in) = tbl_guard.guard_id
```

Comment: How to echo it out on 1 table?
for example
<table>
<tr>
<td>Guard ID</td>
<td>Guard ID IN</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>guard_id</td>
<td>guard_id_in</td>
</tr>
</table>

Comment: i think u are doing unnecessary things. please provide your table structure so i will provide u solution. u are printing same thing in both place. echo "<td>$guard</td>";
        echo "<td>$act_timein</td>";
        echo "<td>$guard</td>";

Answer (score 1):

Just to be sure, your tbl_records table can have a link to two different tbl_guards via guard_id and guard_id_in ?

Maybe you can try :

```
SELECT tbl_records.*, tbl_guard.fname, tbl_guard.lname FROM tbl_records LEFT JOIN tbl_guard ON tbl_guard.guard_id IN (tbl_records.guard_id, tbl_records.guard_id_in)
```

Comment: If you want only one row at the end you should add 
`GROUP BY tbl_guard.guard_id`
At the end of your query

Comment: Then you should select twice the guard table :

Comment: [Here](http://paste.ofcode.org/YU79qGhHjsiZaT2Jeq33tn) is my working code, but it looks dirty I guess

Comment: please see my other answer , you can select the same table twice in a query.

Answer (score 1):

SELECT `tr1`.*, `tg1`.`fname`, `tg2`.lname 
FROM `tbl_records` AS `tr1` 
LEFT JOIN `tbl_guard` AS `tg1` ON `tg1`.`guard_id` = `tr1`.`guard_id`,
LEFT JOIN `tbl_guard` AS `tg2` ON `tg2`.`guard_id` = `trl`.`guard_id_in`

Comment: take tbl_guard as first join `tg1` and for second join `tg2`

Comment: ya sure,
firstly join your tb1_guard as tg1  guard_id with 
SELECT tr1.*, tg1.fname, tg2.lname FROM tbl_records AS tr1 LEFT JOIN tbl_guard AS tg1 ON tg1.guard_id = tr1.guard_id
after it for the guard_id_in take tb1_guard as tg2 and join it

Comment: where did guard_id_in go?